# How to pass multiple actions in matchDispatchToProps? And how to pass in mapStateToprops several state(for each reducer)?

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
function mapStateToProps(state){ 
    return {
        cars: state.cars
    };
}
```

`cars` is a reducer,more precisely - the combineReducer property in which reducer is stored.
In mapStateToProps I need to pass one more state reducer - `motocycle`

```
function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){ 
    return bindActionCreators({select: select}, dispatch) 
}
```

`select` is action
I need to pass one more action - `delete` in matchDispatchToProps

How to write it using Function Declaration and without destructuring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return multiple actions from `mapDispatchToProps` by return an object like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    action1: (options) => dispatch(action1, options),
    action2: (options) => dispatch(action2, options)
  };
}
```

You can also write the same using normal javascript syntax like this:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return {
    action1: (options) => dispatch(action1, options),
    action2: (options) => dispatch(action2, options)
  };
}
```

And then you can dispatch these actions in your code like this:
`this.props.action1(options);`

Hope this helps!!

Comment: thunks, and how to write it using the function declaration?